# Why cannot I accept the answer of my question once I found the right answer within a few minutes after I have asked?.

Tags: discussion

Why cannot I accept the answer of my question once I found the right answer within a few minutes after I have asked? It alert as- You can accept the answer in 2 minutes, in 1 min and so on.